# OpenGL Super Bible 1 source code

Tags: opengl

Can somebody share the source code files for the first edition of the OpenGL Super Bible?
It is available on the [website](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL) but the .zip file is damaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [DiskInternals ZIP Repair](http://www.diskinternals.com/zip-repair/) and it repaired the .zip archive on the book's website for almost 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse the 5th edition source code online at [their google code repo](http://code.google.com/p/oglsuperbible5/source/browse/trunk) until someone comes up with 1st ed. sources, enjoy:)